# Possible to host private docker registries?

Tags: docker, registry, cloud, containers

I'm trying to set up a workflow where I can git pull a docker container from a git repository on a local machine, then push it to a private docker registry where many people can access it. The issue is, I want it so anyone from any machine anywhere will be able to pull from this registry GRANTED they have some sort of authentication. Sort of like a private web hosted docker cloud. Is that possible?

Comment: did you look at: https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#/restricting-access ?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't squeamish, I would thoroughly recommend Portus

```
[https://github.com/SUSE/Portus][1]
```

as a means to secure and manage your registry.

The registry itself can be set up in one command;

```
docker run -d -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy --restart always -v /var/docker/registry/conf:/etc/docker -v /var/docker/registry/data:/var/lib/registry -p 5000:5000 --name registry registry:2
```

See https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/ for a detailed reference.

I generally prefer to run the registry without SSL, offloading all SSL to a shared haproxy (also a docker container).